# Android - How to set a different icon for every child of an ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I've got this java code and I've two questions:

1. I would like to set a different icon for every child of every parent, but with this code I can only set the same icon for all child or an icon for a child situated in a X place and another icon for the other child.
2. What did I do to start an activity when I press, for example, on the item called "Apple"?

How can I solve my problem? Thank you very much.

```
public class sedactivity extends ExpandableListActivity { 
    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
    private final static String NAME = "NAME";
    private final static String SURNAME = "SURNAME";
    private Resources res;
    private Drawable photo, photo2, photo3, photo4;
    private List<Drawable> albumCovers;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

            // Create a List of Drawables to insert into the Expandable List
            // This can be completely dynamic
            res = this.getResources();
            photo = (Drawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bee);
            photo2 = (Drawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.astro);
            photo3 = (Drawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bomb);
            photo4 = (Drawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.apple);
            albumCovers = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
            albumCovers.add(photo);
            albumCovers.add(photo2);

            // The following code simply generates the Expandable Lists content (Strings)
            List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
            Map<String, String>


            //List A
            curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);

            curGroupMap.put(NAME, "A");
            curGroupMap.put(SURNAME, "(2 Photos)");



            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);


            curChildMap.put(NAME, "Apple");


            curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);

            curChildMap.put(NAME, "Astro");

            curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);


            childData.add(children);


            //List B
            curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);


            curGroupMap.put(NAME, "B");
            curGroupMap.put(SURNAME, "(2 Photos)");

            children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);

            curChildMap.put(NAME, "Bee");

            curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);

            curChildMap.put(NAME, "Bomb");

            curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);


            childData.add(children);


            //List C
            curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);


            curGroupMap.put(NAME, "C");
            curGroupMap.put(SURNAME, "(0 Photo)");

            children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


            childData.add(children);

            // Set up our adapter
            mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(
                            this,
                            groupData,
                            R.layout.list_parent,
                            new String[] { NAME, SURNAME },
                            new int[] { R.id.rowText1, R.id.rowText2,R.id.photoAlbumImg },
                            childData,
                            R.layout.list_child,
                            new String[] { NAME, SURNAME },
                            new int[] { R.id.rowText1, R.id.photoAlbumImg }
                    );
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
    }


    /**
     * A simple adapter which allows you to bind data to specific
     * Views defined within the layout of an Expandable Lists children
     * (Implement getGroupView() to define the layout of parents)
     */


    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleExpandableListAdapter {

            private List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> mChildData;
            private String[] mChildFrom;
            private int[] mChildTo;

            public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout,
                            String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                            List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,
                            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
                    super(context, groupData, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                          childData, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);

                    mChildData = childData;
                    mChildFrom = childFrom;
                    mChildTo = childTo;

            }

            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {
                    v = newChildView(isLastChild, parent);
            } else {
                    v = convertView;
            }
            bindView(v, mChildData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition), mChildFrom,
                            mChildTo, groupPosition, childPosition);
            return v;

            }

         // This method binds my data to the Views specified in the child xml layout
            private void bindView(View view, Map<String, ?> data, String[] from, int[] to, int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                    int len = to.length - 1;
                    // Apply TextViews
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                            TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(to[i]);
                            if (v != null) {
                                    v.setText((String) data.get(from[i]));
                            }
                            // Apply ImageView
                            ImageView imgV = (ImageView) view.findViewById(to[1]);
                            if (imgV != null) {
                                if(childPosition % 1 == 0) imgV.setImageDrawable(albumCovers.get(0));
                                else imgV.setImageDrawable(albumCovers.get(1));
                        }


                    }

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
imgV.setImageDrawable(albumCovers.get(1))
```

in your `bindView` method sets the image for the child view. You can set it to whatever you want, can make it data specific (say you have an image url in the data represented by this view, you can set the `imgV` to display that image.

To attach a `View.OnClickListener` to every child item, you simply set it either in the overridden `getChildView` (for `v/convertView`) or your `bindView` method (for `view`):

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO: Implement the tasks to be done here 
    }
});
```

**Update 1**
if you certainly have a drawable defined with the name that is shown in your list, you can update your for cycle as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
                v.setText((String) data.get(from[i]));
        }
        ImageView imgV = (ImageView) view.findViewById(to[1]);
        imgV.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier((String) 
            data.get(from[i]), "drawable", "yourdefaultpackage"));
    }
}
```

just update the `yourdefaultpackage` part with your application's default package.

**Update 2**

Below is a detailed sample for how to proceed when you'd like to have different icons for all of the child rows in an expandable list view based on the data the row holds:

Let's assume the hierarchical data structure to show is:

**res/raw/data.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <group letter="A">
        <child name="American Bull" img="american_bull" />
        <child name="Arco's" img="arcos" />
    </group>
    <group letter="B">
        <child name="Barter" img="barter" />
        <child name="Bitter B." img="bitter_b" />
        <child name="Bull Hunter" img="bull_hunter" />
        <child name="Bull In Cuba" img="bull_in_cuba" />
        <child name="Bullito" img="bullito" />
    </group>
    <group letter="C">
        <child name="Cackle" img="cackle" />
        <child name="Cheapstake" img="cheapstake" />
        <child name="Checco's Bull" img="checcos_bull" />
        <child name="Cheeriness" img="cheeriness" />
        <child name="Cross Current" img="cross_current" />
        <child name="Cruel" img="cruel" />
    </group>
    <group letter="D"></group>
    <group letter="E"></group>
    <group letter="F">
        <child name="Firearm" img="firearm" />
        <child name="First Of All" img="first_of_all" />
        <child name="First Apple" img="first_apple" />
    </group>
    <group letter="G">
        <child name="Golden" img="golden" />
        <child name="Green Bull" img="green_bull" />
    </group>
    <group letter="H">
        <child name="Hollywood Passion" img="hollywood_passion" />
    </group>
    <group letter="I"></group>
    <group letter="J"></group>
    <group letter="K">
        <child name="Kind Bull" img="kind_bull" />
        <child name="Kingling" img="kingling" />
    </group>
    <group letter="L">
        <child name="Lab" img="lab" />
        <child name="Leary" img="leary" />
        <child name="Leg Pull" img="leg_pull" />
        <child name="Long Bull" img="long_bull" />
        <child name="Lucy" img="lucy" />
    </group>
    <group letter="M">
        <child name="Mayla" img="mayla" />
    </group>
    <group letter="N">
        <child name="New Red Bull Fantasy" img="new_red_bull_fantasy" />
        <child name="Nu Energy" img="nu_energy" />
    </group>
    <group letter="O"></group>
    <group letter="P">
        <child name="Passion" img="passion" />
        <child name="Power" img="power" />
    </group>
    <group letter="Q"></group>
    <group letter="R">
        <child name="Rebellion Red Peach" img="rebellion_red_peach" />
        <child name="Red Bulloska" img="red_bulloska" />
        <child name="Red 28" img="red_28" />
        <child name="Red Bull Wallbanger" img="red_bull_wallbanger" />
        <child name="Red Cell" img="red_cell" />
        <child name="Red Hothead" img="red_hothead" />
        <child name="Red Lime" img="red_lime" />
    </group>
    <group letter="S">
        <child name="Speedy" img="speedy" />
        <child name="Spritz Power" img="spritz_power" />
        <child name="Stiff-Necked" img="stiff_necked" />
    </group>
    <group letter="T"></group>
    <group letter="U"></group>
    <group letter="V">
        <child name="Vedi O' Mare Come E' Bull" img="vedi_o_mare_come_e_bull" />
    </group>
    <group letter="W"></group>
    <group letter="X"></group>
    <group letter="Y"></group>
    <group letter="Z"></group>
    <group letter="#"></group>
</data>
```

You need to define your classes to represent this data as java objects. It's simple, basically you need a `Group` that has a `letter` and a `list of Child`, where `Child` has a `name` and an `image`.
So you'll have a `Group.java` and a `Child.java` class with the properties above:

**Group.java:**

```
public class Group
{
    private String letter;
    private ArrayList<Child> children;

    /**
     * @return the letter
     */
    public String getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }

    /**
     * @param letter the letter to set
     */
    public void setLetter(String letter)
    {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    /**
     * @return the children
     */
    public ArrayList<Child> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }

    /**
     * @param children the children to set
     */
    public void setChildren(ArrayList<Child> children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**:

```
public class Child
{
    private String name;
    private String image;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the image
     */
    public String getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * @param image the image to set
     */
    public void setImage(String image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

To read the xml structure into an ArrayList of `Group` objects, you will need a simple xml handler too, which will examine the tags, and build up the structure you need:

**XmlHandler.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    /**
     * The tag- and attribute names in the xml data
     */
    private static final String TAG_GROUP = "group";
    private static final String TAG_CHILD = "child";
    private static final String ATTR_LETTER = "letter";
    private static final String ATTR_NAME = "name";
    private static final String ATTR_IMG = "img";

    /**
     * holds the currently processing Group instance
     */
    private Group currentGroup;
    /**
     * holds the currently processing Child instance
     */
    private Child currentChild;
    /**
     * the list of Group objects parsed from the xml
     */
    private ArrayList<Group> records = null;

    /**
     * @return the list of Group parsed from the xml
     */
    public ArrayList<Group> getGroups()
    {
        return records;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        super.startDocument();
        this.records = new ArrayList<Group>();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String Uri, final String localName, final String qName, 
            final Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName == null)
            return;
        if (localName.equals(TAG_GROUP))//examining a group tag
        {
            currentGroup = new Group();
            currentGroup.setLetter(attributes.getValue(ATTR_LETTER));//the letter attribute
            currentGroup.setChildren(new ArrayList<Child>());
            records.add(currentGroup);
        }
        else if (localName.equals(TAG_CHILD))//examining a child tag
        {
            currentChild = new Child();
            currentChild.setName(attributes.getValue(ATTR_NAME));//the name attribute
            currentChild.setImage(attributes.getValue(ATTR_IMG));//the img attribute
            currentGroup.getChildren().add(currentChild);
        }
    }
}
```

For displaying a list / expandable list, you need an `Adapter` class. In this case we'll use a simple `BaseExpandableListAdapter` implementation to show the parent and child rows with their proper icons:

**MyExpandableListAdapter.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ArrayList<Group> groups;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, final ArrayList<Group> groups)
    {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
    {
        final Group parent = groups.get(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) //if the row is null, we create it (by inflation)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_parent, parentView, false);
        // display the letter of the group:
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowText1)).
            setText(parent.getLetter());
        // display the children count of the group:
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowText2)).
            setText("(" + parent.getChildren().size() + " Ricette)");
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
    {
        final Group group = groups.get(groupPosition);
        final Child child = group.getChildren().get(childPosition);
        if (convertView == null)//if the child row is null, we inflate it
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, parentView, false);
        // display the name of the child on the row:
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowText1)).setText(child.getName());
        // set the proper icon of the child on the child row:
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoAlbumImg)).
            setImageResource(parentView.getResources().
            getIdentifier(child.getImage(), "drawable", "com.test.com"));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged()
    {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return ((groups == null) || groups.isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, the activity class, which uses the above three:

**testactivity.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;

/**
 * Demonstrates expandable lists using a custom {...@link ExpandableListAdapter} 
 * from {...@link BaseExpandableListAdapter}.
 */
public class testactivity extends ExpandableListActivity
{
    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_main);
        // the next line removes the arrow from the expandable list's group rows,
        // that indicates whether the group is expanded or not.
        // I've removed, because this way it looks nicer.
        getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);

        // read in the list of groups from the xml data
        final ArrayList<Group> groups = readGroupsFromXml();

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), groups);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
    }

    /**
     * Parses the data.xml file located in the /res/raw/ folder, 
     * and builds up the list of Group.
     * @return the list of Group instances to display in the list
     */
    public ArrayList<Group> readGroupsFromXml()
    {
        try
        {
            // initialize our handler
            final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
            // instantiate a SAXParser for parsing the xml document
            final SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            // parse the /res/raw/data.xml file 
            // (referenced by R.raw.data) using our handler
            sp.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().
                    openRawResource(R.raw.data), handler);
            // return the list of Group built inside the handler
            return handler.getGroups();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", "xml", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Creo il menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Creo le azioni per i tasti del menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.Home:
                return true;
            case R.id.Cerca:
                return true;
            case R.id.Glossario:
                // Inserire azione
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can work it out this way.

Comment: In my xml file there's an imageview at the left of a textview. What I would like do is set a different image for every child but this part of code `if(childPosition % 1 == 0)` set the same image to every child that are in first position in every group. So I would like to set the image "Apple" beside the text "Apple" and the image "Bee" beside the text "Bee".

Comment: It's more difficult that I thought. This is my first application and I don't know many things about Android. I put your string in my code and I received an error to the `setImageDrawable`, I tried to put an image to "drawable" but the error goes to `getIdentifier`. Maybe (certainly) it's me that I don't understand what I do.

Comment: You need to have the "Bee.jpg", "Apple.jpg" (or png, ..) inside your project's /res/drawable directory, and the code will work.

Comment: Yes every image is inside my project. I tried every combination but I receive always an error. I put your update at the end of the project, where it's written //Apply ImageView, maybe I need to do other things to work it or maybe I'm wrong something.

Comment: Could you temporarily upload your project to github, or share it somhow, to let me take take a look at it as a whole,  and debug?

Comment: i'll take a look, and let you know!

Comment: the first thing is my mistake, it's not `setImageDrawable` but `setImageResource`, sorry about that. On the other hand, I can't find the images for 'Barter', 'Bullito', etc.. But you should really rather use an xml data structure for this, not a hardcoded super-complicated List-List-Map structure. I update my answer to correct that `setImageResource` call, let me know if you'd like to simplify your class using xml.

Comment: I forgot to post a simplified version to you with only few things. Imagine that I need to set that four images to children but I want to choose the image for every single children. If you think that your method is better I can only say "Yes I do, thank you very much".

Comment: i've started to post a walk-through to achieve your goal. please take a look at the xml structure; do you agree it's correct? the `img` attributes should be the file names of the images to show near every child item, so you must have them inside your `/res/drawable...` folder (near Apple.png). They can be jpg, png, ... But it's a good practice to have their names in lower case, and also, remove all `'` characters, and convert all spaces to `_` (underscore) in these filenames (to avoid compile errors). So for each child item in the xml you must have the proper image file as in `img` attribute.

Comment: I thought that into the folder raw went only audio files. The file data seems more simple than my xml files.

Comment: You put this xml here, so the compiler won't try to understand it (it's your data, not a layout/drawable/etc), you'll deal with it.

Comment: But I can put more than one xml data into raw and call the other one with another name, or I can put only one file called data?

Comment: it's a file structure, so inside the `raw` directory you can't put another `data.xml`. But it's not necessary to call it `data.xml`, you can give any other name.

Comment: I've posted a working implementation with explanation, but if it's not clear, feel free to ask. Don't forget to place the necessary images into your `/res/drawable` folder with a name that matches the `img` attribute in the `data.xml` file. If you change the name of `data.xml`, you have to update the reference in the `readGroupsFromXml` method too.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. The only thing I adjusted was to remove some @Override annotation into the MyExpandableListAdapter, but it works. Now if I want to start a different activity for every child where do I need to put the code?

Comment: You can override the onChildClick method of your Activity, and start the different activities there. But are you certain, that you need a lot of different activities? Wouldn't be enough a single activity with dynamic content determined by the child item you've just clicked?

Comment: I thought to set a xml layout as default background for all the activities of the child and then, for every child, write an activity. In effect they are a lot of child and activities but I don't know other ways.

Comment: If your layout is common for all the activities, you really should use just one activity, and based on the clicked item populate your layout with the proper data. You should ask a new question about this though, since this answer and list of comments are huge already...

Comment: Please let me know where to share the sample which uses a single `Details` activity and its display depends on what child item you've clicked.